# perform math operations with a group of data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

given a list of numbers
Eg:

```
data = [30.5, 31.01, 30.4, 30.01, 29.5, 29.6, 29.63, 30.5, 30.33, 30.2]
```

I need to create a function which subtracts the second element from the first element, the third element from the second element and so on, until the operation is completed with all elements of the group

```
(Eg: 31.01 - 30.5, 30.4 - 31.01......)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use `zip` to iterate two list.
- following code will achive that.

```
data = [30.5, 31.01, 30.4, 30.01, 29.5, 29.6, 29.63, 30.5, 30.33, 30.2]
print([y-x for x,y in zip(data, data[1:])])
```

- output

```
[0.5100000000000016, -0.610000000000003, -0.389999999999997, -0.5100000000000016, 0.10000000000000142, 0.029999999999997584, 0.870000000000001, -0.1700000000000017, -0.129999999999999]
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged `pandas`, so here is a simple solution using `shift()`:

```
data = [30.5, 31.01, 30.4, 30.01, 29.5, 29.6, 29.63, 30.5, 30.33, 30.2]
data = pd.Series(data)
data - data.shift()

0     NaN
1    0.51
2   -0.61
3   -0.39
4   -0.51
5    0.10
6    0.03
7    0.87
8   -0.17
9   -0.13
```